# Cocos2d: Black screen when removing sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently doing the tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial .
I have a problem on the part that reacts to when a ninja star hits the monsters. My code is:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {    
    NSMutableArray *projectilesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (CCSprite *projectile in _projectiles) {

        NSMutableArray *monstersToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (CCSprite *monster in _monsters) {
            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(projectile.boundingBox, monster.boundingBox)) {
                [monstersToDelete addObject:monster];
            }
        }

        for (CCSprite *monster in monstersToDelete) {
            [_monsters removeObject:monster];
            [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        }

        if (monstersToDelete.count > 0) {
            [projectilesToDelete addObject:projectile];
        }
        [monstersToDelete release];
    }

    for (CCSprite *projectile in projectilesToDelete) {
        [_projectiles removeObject:projectile];
        [self removeChild:projectile cleanup:YES];
    }
    [projectilesToDelete release];

}
```

which works okay, does not crash, but when I hit a monster with an projectile, the screen turns black on the simulator. No error or anything. I logged the CGRectIntersectRect, and it records as it is supposed to. The problem is that when this happens, it all turns black. Any idea why?

Comment: [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];  What is a self in this context ? maybe just maybe

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Wouldn't that be the monster object?

Comment: not certain what the object model here, could be the layer embedding the game controller here. Not certain. It sounds 'fishy' that a an object running a piece of logic would delete itself in the middle of doing the work. Maybe OP needs another loop after the main loop to loop over the monsters to delete and scrap them.

Comment: You may also want to look in to the array method `removeObjectsInArray: (NSArray *) array`. Much easier than manually iterating the array of objects you wish to remove from another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the tutorial, and the line i identified in the comments above reads :

```
[self removeChild:monster cleanup:YES];
```

Try that.

Comment: I usually prefer `[monster removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]`, that way your code doesn't break when you change the parent of `monster`.

Comment: true in principle ... I just copied the line straight from the tutorial, just to get Sophia going again. But since self seems to be the parent of monster, not a big difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES] which removes your current layer from the parent. So you get a black screen.

You probably want to remove the child monster from the layer instead.